# как применить функция tapply?

Tags: r

есть датафрейм, и при помощи функции **tapply** надо вывести среднее число женщин по странам за все года, но что бы я не вставляла в аргументы tapply выходит совсем не то, что надо

```
DL <- data.frame(time = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1","1", "2","2","2","2","2","2"),
             country = c("Spain", "Spain","Spain","Germany", "Germany", "Germany","Spain","Spain","Spain","Germany","Germany","Germany"),
             sex = c("Total", "Females", "Males","Total", "Females", "Males","Total", "Females", "Males","Total", "Females", "Males"), 
             values = c("10000", "5000", "5000", "15000", "9000", "6000", "11000", "6000", "5000", "14000", "8500", "5500")
            )
```

что мне стоит вставить в аргументы функции? я окончательно запуталась

Answer (score 0):

у вас тут получаются две проблемы, одна следует из другой:

1. вместо чисел в переменную values были записаны строки
2. при создании таблицы функцией `data.frame()` эта переменная (именно из-за того, что в ней содержатся строки) была преобразована в факторную.

возможны как минимум три выхода:

1. преобразовывать «на лету», во время вызова функции `tapply()`

   ```r
    tapply(as.numeric(as.character(DL$values)), DL$sex, mean)
    #> Females   Males   Total 
    #>    7125    5375   12500
   ```
2. преобразовать уже созданную факторную переменную в числовую:

   ```r
    DL$values=as.numeric(as.character(DL$values))
    tapply(DL$values, DL$sex, mean)
    #> Females   Males   Total 
    #>    7125    5375   12500
   ```
3. создавать изначально числовую переменную (`values = c(10000, 5000, ...`). тогда можно будет применить функцию `tapply()` без дополнительных преобразований:

   ```r
    DL <- data.frame(time = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1","1", "2","2","2","2","2","2"),
                 country = c("Spain", "Spain","Spain","Germany", "Germany", "Germany","Spain","Spain","Spain","Germany","Germany","Germany"),
                 sex = c("Total", "Females", "Males","Total", "Females", "Males","Total", "Females", "Males","Total", "Females", "Males"),
                 values = c(10000, 5000, 5000, 15000, 9000, 6000, 11000, 6000, 5000, 14000, 8500, 5500)
                )
    tapply(DL$values, DL$sex, mean)
    #> Females   Males   Total 
    #>    7125    5375   12500
   ```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>